# Using twice the Saxon genitive

Tags: american-english, british-english

I have a question about Saxon genitive. Which of the following sentence is correct ?

> Pac-Man was the video game that shattered the Arcade's Pandora’s box

Or

> Pac-Man was the video game that shattered the Arcade's Pandora box

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Of course, you mean "English" and not "Saxon" which would presumably mean Old English. I tried to create a snarky translation of this sentence into Old English but the translator choked on "Arcade" and "Pandora".  _...þæt déorfriþ þæt gebræc..._ "Pac-Mán" was a particularly evil word.

Comment: @Spencer 'Saxon' refers to its [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Arcade had a copy of *Pandora’s Box*, then it’s the Arcade’s *Pandora’s Box*. (I’m presuming that’s a game, not her real box, but it doesn’t matter.)

You can stack as many of these as you like, even if it’s the Queen of England’s kennel’s dogs’ fleas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Just a small addition: would it be correct as well "the Pandora's box of Arcade games" which in a way reflects exactly my thought (just I'm not totally sure it's grammatically correct). Thanks

Comment: @FrancescoMarchioni Yes, and in fact more likely if you’re speaking of it metaphorically rather than as the same of a game.